# Accessing an audio file using ReadFile in FileApi of C++

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-phone, readfile, fileapi

I am trying to read an **Audio file** from the isolated storage on the **windows phone**.

*pHandle* is the handle that I get to the file. I am even getting the path to the file. The *ReadFile* function gives a *TRUE* value as well.

I am stuck here to access the file itself. Reading the file is good, but getting its contents is another thing. Also, display the output of the audio file that is being read in the binary format.

How can I do this?

```
#define BUFFERSIZE 4096

BYTE ReadBuffer[BUFFERSIZE];
DWORD dwBytesRead = 0;

if (pHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    printf("Could not Read the Audio File.");
    return;
}

if(hrReadHandle == S_OK)
{
    // Shows if the music can be read or not
    if(FALSE == ReadFile(pHandle,ReadBuffer, BUFFERSIZE-1,&dwBytesRead, NULL))
    {
        stdOperationHeader = L"File Read Failure";
        OutputDebugStringW(stdOperationHeader.c_str());
        GetLastError();
    }else {
        stdOperationHeader = L"File read";
        OutputDebugStringW(stdOperationHeader.c_str());
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to get the contents of the file i have a handle on. ?

Comment: You are already doing that with `ReadFile`.

Comment: I am not able to retrieve the contents of the file. Any pointers there ?

Comment: Your code is reading the file. What happens when you run the code?

Comment: It just returns true as i can find the file in the isolated storage. But I need to get the size of the file and retrieve the contents.

Comment: Your code does not attempt to find the size.

Comment: Right. It does not. When i use GetFileSize(). It gives me an error as well. Saying its an unidentified function.

Comment: I suggest you give a complete program and verbatim error messages.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540534%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I am following this example. I get a handle using one of the propitiatory libraries, then i try reading the file above. I would like to know how to get the contents of the file after reading.

Comment: Call ReadFile to do that. If you want help, supply an SSCCE.